# My table data got deleted when i restart my spring boot application after changing the value of 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My table data got deleted when i restart my spring boot application after changing the value of 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto' to 'create' from 'verify'. why it is so? what should i do to get my data back?

I could see some drop query executing in my IDE console. Why it happened? can someone please explain?

Answer (score 5):

Make the following change in application.properties

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Answer (score 1):

You can read the official document of [spring-boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases).And the property is related to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in [hibernate configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-properties).

Comment: This solved my problem. Actually the spring documentation has all the values to be set for db actions upon restart

Answer (score 0):

Just change table name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hms_pinlocator")
```